# How to add a playground on XCode iOS Swift project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-playground

I've a project with HTTP requests. I wants test these requestes at runtime, on differents forms and params. I can use a playground to do this? Because I need execute the app every change and if I've a playground I can test requests quickly. I'm using Alamofire.

Comment: Wouldn't a UI or unit test be a better approach? You could just create a suite of "different forms and params" and just run through them at the push of a button.

Comment: Yes, I could. But the playground is better option.